# Jquery NiceScroll not working in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-9, scrollbar, nicescroll

I am using nicescroll for the scroll in a fancybox. Its working perfect in chrome and firefox. But not working even in ie9. But the plugin says its support ie6+ And its also popularly used plugin.

```
   jQuery(function($) {


        $(document).ready(function()
        {

          $(".popcontent").niceScroll({cursorwidth:"8", autohidemode: "false" });


        });

     });
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. This was dropped and standard one used.